# Firebird SQL auto-increment

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou fazendo um curso de SQL/Modelagem
no mysql a criação de uma tabela composta ficaria assim:

```
USE banco;
CREATE TABLE clientes(
   cli_id integer not null auto_increment,
   cli_nome varchar(20) not null,
   cli_email varchar(30) not null
primary key (cli_id)
); /*Cria a tabela no mysql*/
```

OK, agora no firebird eu tenho que fazer:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
   cli_id integer not null auto_increment,
   cli_nome varchar(20) not null,
   cli_email varchar(30) not null
primary key (cli_id)
); /*cria a tabela no firebird*/
create generator gen_cidades_id /*Cria gerador auto increment*/
SET TERM ^
   CREATE TRIGGER TR_CIDADES FOR CIDADES
   ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
      AS
BEGIN
    new.CID_CODIGO =gen_id(ge_cidades_id, 1);
END ^
```

Não há outra forma de se fazer o auto_increment, no firebird além dessa ? pois essa parte aqui:

```
create generator gen_cidades_id /*Cria gerador auto increment*/
SET TERM ^
  CREATE TRIGGER TR_CIDADES FOR CIDADES
  ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  new.CID_CODIGO =gen_id(ge_cidades_id, 1);
END ^
```

Não entendi ela e é bem complicada, ao meu ver.

Comment: Creio que o MySQL também cria um gerador e um _trigger_, só que de forma intransparente.

Comment: Lembrando que o "generated by default as identity" cria de forma transparente uma sequence e um trigger. "id integer generated by default as identity primary key"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, o Firebird não oferece outra forma de implementar coluna auto-incremento além desta.

Eventualmente você pode usar outros recursos do Firebird e inventar outra forma, mas a forma oferecida pela ferramenta é esta.

E não há nada de errado nisso. O Firebird segue o padrão **SEQUENCE** da SQL, o mesmo implementado por outros grandes bancos.

### Explicando o código do Firebird

A indentação do seu código pode estar aumentando a confusão. `CREATE GENERATOR` é uma coisa e `CREATE TRIGGER` é outra. O segundo não é parte do corpo do primeiro como sua indentação sugere.

Modifiquei os comentários para explicar o código:

```
/*Cria uma sequence ou generator chamada gen_cidades_id */
create generator gen_cidades_id

/*Cria uma trigger que será disparada quando 
 um novo registro for inserido em CIDADES.
 Esta trigger solicitará um novo valor 
 para a coluna CID_CODIGO */
SET TERM ^
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CIDADES FOR CIDADES
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
    /* "gen_id" é uma função do Firebird.
     É esta função quem de fato cria um novo valor para a sequence "ge_cidades_id",
     incrementado em 1 conforme informado no segundo parâmetro. */
    new.CID_CODIGO =gen_id(ge_cidades_id, 1);
END ^
```

Veja que a instrução `auto_increment` na criação da tabela não é, em si, o recurso auto-incremento do Firebird.

Esta instrução é dispensável para criação de colunas auto-incremento. No seu caso, `auto_increment` é um tipo definido pelo usuário do seu banco de dados, e provavelmente está apenas determinando de maneira redundante o tipo do campo (inteiro). Se você retirar o `auto_increment` do `create table`, a sequence continuará funcionando normalmente.

### Conclusão

O Firebird segue o padrão SQL para colunas auto-incremento. Neste padrão, são utilizados dois recursos: **SEQUENCE**, que é capaz de obter um incremento numérico, e **TRIGGER**, que é um gatilho disparado a cada nova inserção. Neste gatilho, o recurso da SEQUENCE é utilizado para preencher a coluna auto-incremento.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação..

Answer (score 1):

No Firebird 3, agora tem suporte a campo auto-incremento:

```
id integer generated by default as identity primary key
```