# Como pegar o próximo ID a ser inserido?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu gostaria de pegar o próximo ID a ser inserido, algo do tipo:

```
$ultimoid = (DB::lastInsertId());
$futuroid = ( $ultimoid + 1 );
```

O objetivo é conhecer previamente o ID que será utilizado no meu INSERT pois antes ainda de inserir o registro é necessário salvar um arquivo em uma pasta cujo nome referencia o ID deste registro.

Comment: O `lastInsertId` é o que acabou de ser criado. Não é isso que você precisa? Por que o `+1` no título? Por favor esclareça a pergunta.

Comment: é pq no caso eu iria criar o diretorio e upar a imagem antes mesmo de ser criado o ID

Comment: PDO :: lastInsertId - Retorna o ID da última linha inserida ou valor de seqüência como vou saber qual se é o valor do ultimo id ja preenchido ou o da sequencia?

Comment: É o último preenchido. Até tem como saber o próximo (no mysql pelo menos), mas não tem como garantir que esse próximo será de fato o que você vai ganhar na hora da inserção (porque pode ter mais de um usuário acessando ao mesmo tempo, entre outros fatores). Recomendo preencher a linha e pegar o último id inserido, mesmo que depois seja necessário fazer um update no registro.

Comment: então nesse caso teria mesmo que somar +1 para a criação da pasta mesmo , ja que a ação de criar e inserir seria no mesmo instante seria quase impossivel de ser criado a pasta diferente do id correto .. tks pela duvida tirada

Comment: Acho que você está entendendo errado o uso do lastInsertId. Ele vai retornar o id gerado pela query imediatamente anterior.

Comment: to meio confuso, pra ficar claro para mim supondo que na minha tabela noticias o ultimo id seja 71. se eu chamar $ultimoid = (DB::lastInsertId(); ele vai me retornar 71 ou 72?

Comment: Vai retornar 71. Mas se não me engano pode nem retornar nada ou dar erro se você não executar logo depois do insert.

Comment: @ArsomNolasco porque tentar adivinhar o ID seguinte ? Não pode fazer o upload da imagem depois do insert? (Acredite: o quase impossível de usuários simultâneos acontece)

Comment: Porque é que esta pergunta tem -5 e está a ser votada para fechar?

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2377/como-pegar-o-pr%C3%B3ximo-id-a-ser-inserido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta é uma necessidade bastante comum e em outros bancos de dados é resolvido com **SEQUENCE**.

**Sequence** é diferente de **auto incremento** pois usando sequence você (ou o framework ou o banco de dados através de uma trigger) primeiro obtém o próximo ID, reservando este ID, e depois, mesmo que muito mais tarde e até em outra transação, o ID pode ser usado tranquilamente porque será único - a **sequence** nunca mais entregará novamente aquele mesmo ID (a não ser que ela seja *resetada*).

Infelizmente o MySql não possui este recurso ainda, ele possui apenas o **auto incremento** simples de modo que você não pode reservar um ID.

Você poderia criar uma função que se comporte como uma **sequence** verdadeira, mas é bastante trabalhoso pois você tem que garantir por exemplo o controle de concorrência e ainda terá que criar manualmente uma trigger para cada tabela onde queira utilizar este recuros.

Aqui tem um exemplo de como o recurso **auto incremento** é implementado através do uso de **sequence** em outros bancos de dados: [Firebird SQL auto-increment](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41614/14584).